# Clear preview image after submit

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

In my contact form7 I use this code to preview a upload image:

```
[file fileuploader filetypes:jpg id:uploader]
<img id="preview" src="#" />
<script>
var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
uploader.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  var binaryData = [];
  binaryData.push(document.getElementById('uploader').files);
  if (binaryData) preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(binaryData[0][0]);
});
</script>
```

When submit the form, all fields are cleared except for the image preview.
How can I clear this preview?

Answer (score 0):

in form submit function make the src of preview # like

```
preview.src = '#'
```

Comment: I have little experience in php code.
What would be the php instruction to execute what you suggest?